# How to display a tabular list-view in ember-cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

What is the best current way to use Ember.ListView in Ember CLI to display tabular data with a table header? (With the new syntax, now that the `{{collection}}` helper is deprecated)

Right now I have a sortable table and use `{{#each ...}}` to generate a very long list of 's. Extending CollectionView with a tagName such as 'tbody' works to create a similar result. This is fine but scrolls the entire page.

Anyone know how to do the same thing with Ember.ListView (or better Ember.VirtualListView) so that the contents of `<tbody>` are in the scrollable area?

Also, I have tried the addepar ember-table, but it is not up to date with the current ember and works poorly with ember-cli, so I would really prefer to use ListView because it seems to be better supported by the community.